# How to include a folder with files while publishing windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, ssis

I have a windows forms application through which I am running SSIS packages. I have created SSIS packages and placed .dtsx files in a folder.

Now while I am deploying my solution using click one, how do I include these as application files?

Currently the project publish properties does not show these files even if I include it in my solution.

I cannot include these files as a resource file, because based on the user selection I will be selecting a specific .dtsx file say, entityname_targetname.dtsx as path and file name. 
Because DTS.Application.LoadPAckage method expects a file name and not a resource name.

Comment: Refer to the solution in the link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64983717/c-sharp-publish-exe-of-windows-form-application-with-folder-data

Answer (score 1):

You have probably figured it out till now, but I encountered the same problem and this is how I fixed it:

`Right click on Project -> Add -> Existing item -> Search for your files and add them directly to project or under a folder -> In the Solution Explorer, click on the added file -> Properties -> Set Build Actions to Content and Copy to Output Directory to Always Copy`

Now the files will be added to your deployment.

Answer (score 0):

After adding it your solution, right click the respective file and choose Properties. Then select appropriate value in "Copy to Output Directory". This will add the files in the folder in which your main executable is placed after ClickOnce deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is working when executed from the source code. But when published and installed in another machine, Those files are not coming.    I have programmatically copied the files to destination folder by copying it from resource file.